# Do changes to datatypes on an established data-sync throw errors?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-data-sync

Our MI reporting solution involves pulling data on-prem into a DMZ from an Azure SQL server, via Azure Data-Sync, then performing ETL processes on it etc. The Azure SQL server is maintained by a third party who keeps adding columns to existing tables etc. and there currently  aren't suitable change tracking protocols to get this information to us.

In our pre-production server they have altered a column's datatype, which is already established in the Data-Sync, from smallint to nvarchar(50).

[This lovely post](https://www.francoisdelport.com/2017/07/how-to-handle-schema-changes-in-azure-sql-data-sync/) outlines how to handle the schema changes, however it doesn't outline behaviour for when the schema change isn't properly handled...

When this change gets pushed to production, will it break the data-sync?

Comment: My guess, is yes.

Comment: It would potentially break data-sync, if you can not alter back datatype in Azure portal, it could be good to handle in ETL packages, Unfortunately, it is only way as u said third party manages destination portal or Ask third party to follow change control process before making any changes to schema, objects and datatypes